# Simple screen recorder(ssr) no funciona audio interno

Tags: appcenter, system, audio

Estoy usando eoS Hera 5.1.7

Tengo instalado el simplescreenrecorder de la store de eos pero el problema es que cuando reproduzco la grabación que realice no se escucha el audio interno del sistema,he probado otras apps que también ofrece eos como screen cast, screen recorder o screenrec y en el caso de estas tres no tengo problema el audio interno se escucha perfecto.
También intenté instalar el simplescreenrecorder de la tienda de snap-store y tampoco funcionó
Alguien me podría ayudar por favor  ya que no se porque en el caso de simplescreenrecorder no funciona y en los otros si me gustaría que alguien me pudiera ayudar con este problema.

[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

Claro que lo graba, sólo hay que escoger la fuente de sonido adecuada. Busca un tutorial en youtube de simplescreenrecorder de yoyo fernandez. Ahí lo tienes todo explicado.